# iOS Convert Facebook Graph JSON result to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, facebook, nsmutablearray

I use

```
 if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
        [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"/v2.3/116178611870507/feed?limit=2" parameters:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"id, message, picture" forKey:@"fields"]]
         startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {
                NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);


             }
             else {
                 NSLog(@"%@", error);
             }
         }];
    }
```

and get:

```
{
    data =     (
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-08-08T13:19:59+0000";
            id = "FirstID";
            message = "First Message";
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-08-07T13:34:20+0000";
            id = "THE ID";
            message = "Message Content";
        }
    );
```

I would like to get this into an `NSMutableArray` to allow for easier creation of a tableview, using this data.  How can I go about converting it, as it contains a lot of non `UTF-8` such as `\u2019`?

Here is the non-edited result code I get for the open graph request.  As you can see in it, there are numerous non UTF-8 elements such as `/u2019` instead of `'`.  I just need to put this into an array, while converting all those elements.:

```
{
    data =     (
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-08-08T13:19:59+0000";
            id = "116178611870507_533557810132583";
            message = "10 HABITS OF HAPPY COUPLES\n\nWhat does it take to be happy in a relationship? If you\U2019re working to improve your marriage, here are the 10 habits of happy couples.\n\n1. GO TO BED AT THE SAME TIME. Remember the beginning of your relationship, when you couldn\U2019t wait to go to bed with each other to make love? Happy couples resist the temptation to go to bed at different times. They go to bed at the same time, even if one partner wakes up later to do things while their partner sleeps. And when their skins touch it still causes each of them to tingle and unless one or both are completely exhausted to feel sexually excited.\n\n2. CULTIVATE COMMON INTERESTS. After the passion settles down, it\U2019s common to realize that you have few interests in common. But don\U2019t minimize the importance of activities you can do together that you both enjoy. If common interests are not present, happy couples develop them. At the same time, be sure to cultivate interests of your own; this will make you more interesting to your mate and prevent you from appearing too dependent.\n\n3. WALK HAND IN HAND OR SIDE BY SIDE. Do things together. Rather than one partner lagging or dragging behind the other, happy couples walk comfortably hand in hand or side by side. They know it\U2019s more important to be with their spouse than to see the sights along the way.\n\n4. MAKE TRUST AND FORGIVENESS YOUR DEFAULT MODE. If and when they have a disagreement or argument, and if they can\U2019t resolve it, happy couples default to trusting and forgiving rather than distrusting and begrudging.\n\n5. FOCUS MORE ON WHAT YOUR SPOUSE DOES RIGHT THAN WHAT HE OR SHE DOES WRONG. If you look for things your partner does wrong, you can always find something. If you look for what he or she does right, you can always find something, too. It all depends on what you want to look for. Happy couples accentuate the positive.\n\n6. HUG EACH OTHER AS SOON AS YOU SEE EACH OTHER AFTER WORK. Our skin has a memory of \U201cgood touch\U201d (loved), \U201cbad touch\U201d (abused) and \U201cno touch\U201d (neglected). Couples who say hello with a hug keep their skin bathed in the \U201cgood touch,\U201d which can inoculate your spirit against anonymity in the world.\n\n7. SAY \"I LOVE YOU\" AND \"HAVE A GOOD DAY\" EVERY MORNING. This is a great way to buy some patience and tolerance as each partner sets out each day to battle traffic jams, long lines and other annoyances.\n\n8. SAY \"GOOD NIGHT\" EVERY NIGHT, REGARDLESS OF HOW YOU FEEL. This tells your partner that, regardless of how upset you are with him or her, you still want to be in the relationship. It says that what you and your partner have is bigger than any single upsetting incident.\n\n9. DO A \"WEATHER\" CHECK DURING THE DAY. Call your spouse at home or at work to see how his or her day is going. This is a great way to adjust expectations so that you\U2019re more in sync when you connect after work. For instance, if your partner is having an awful day, it might be unreasonable to expect him or her to be enthusiastic about something good that happened to you.\n\n10. BE PROUD TO BE SEEN WITH YOUR SPOUSE. Happy couples are pleased to be seen together and are often in some kind of affectionate contact \U2014 hand on hand or hand on shoulder or knee or back of neck. They are not showing off but rather just saying that they belong with each other.\n\nHappy couples have different habits than unhappy couples. A habit is a discrete behavior that you do automatically and that takes little effort to maintain. It takes 21 days of daily repetition of a new a behavior to become a habit. So select one of the behaviors in the list above to do for 21 days and voila, it will become a habit\U2026and make you happier as a couple. And if you fall off the wagon, don\U2019t despair, just apologize to your partner, ask their forgiveness and recommit yourself to getting back in the habit. ~ Dr. Mark Goulson";
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-08-07T13:34:20+0000";
            id = "116178611870507_533189820169382";
            message = "31 DUMB WAYS TO KILL YOUR MARRIAGE: \n\nThere are probably hundreds of dumb things to do in your marriage, but here are 31 that will destroy your marriage\U2026\n\n1. Believe that your marriage will be great without having to invest time or effort into it.\n\n2. NEVER compliment your spouse.\n\n3. Stop pursuing your spouse like you did before marriage.\n\n4. Be critical all the time.\n\n5. Demand that your spouse meets your needs.\n\n6. Pout when you don\U2019t get your way.\n\n7. Consider sex a chore and only do it because you feel obligated.\n\n8. Use the silent treatment when you are mad.\n\n9. Get angry \U2026 often.\n\n10. Flirt with people other than your spouse.\n\n11. Tell your spouse they need to make changes, but you make no effort to change.\n\n12. Never be willing to meet your spouse\U2019s needs.\n\n13. Make no effort to improve yourself or your marriage.\n\n14. Speak negatively about your spouse around other people.\n\n15. Make no effort to keep yourself \U201clooking good\U201d for your spouse.\n\n16. Use derogatory words like stupid, dumb, ignorant and idiot.\n\n17. Always blame your spouse for the problems. It\U2019s never your fault.\n\n18. Take your mate for granted.\n\n19. Quit trying to impress your spouse (you\U2019re married, it\U2019s not needed anymore).\n\n20. Withhold sex.\n\n21. Never take any time to get away without the kids.\n\n22. Don\U2019t tell your spouse how much you love or appreciate them. Just expect them to know it.\n\n23. Be dishonest.\n\n24. When arguing \U2026 bring up old stuff from the past.\n\n25. Have a short fuse.\n\n26. Feel that God is an option in your marriage, not an essential.\n\n27. When angry be verbally abusive.\n\n28. Never seek outside help when you have problems.\n\n29. Have an \U201cit\U2019s my way or the highway\U201d attitude.\n\n30. Spend more time with your friends than your spouse.\n\n31. Never say, \U201cI love you.";
        }
    );
```

Here is my full code.  Since there are 2 posts, I expect to have 2 objects in my NSMutableArray, and for each object in the array, use the RSSEntry class to sort through and create a new NSMutableArray from that.  However, I only get 1 item in the NSMutableArray I create.

```
 if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
        [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"/v2.3/116178611870507/feed?limit=2" parameters:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"id, message, picture" forKey:@"fields"]]
         startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {
               // NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);
                 self.arrayName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
                 [self.arrayName addObject:[result objectForKey:@"data"]];
                // NSLog(@"%@", self.arrayName);
                 int i;
                 NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[self.arrayName count]);
                 for (i = 0; i < [self.arrayName count]; i++) {
                     id myArrayElement = [self.arrayName objectAtIndex:i];
                     NSString *theMessage = [myArrayElement valueForKey:@"message"];
                    // NSLog(@"%@", theMessage);
                     RSSEntry *entry = [[[RSSEntry alloc] initWithBlogTitle:@"Test"

                                                               articleTitle:@"Testing"
                                                                 articleUrl:@"TestingURL"
                                                                articleDate:[NSDate date]
                                                               articleImage:theMessage] autorelease];
                     [self.theEntries addObject:entry];

                         }
                 NSLog(@"%@", self.theEntries);

             }
             else {
                 NSLog(@"%@", error);
             }
         }];
    }
```

Comment: Update your question with an example of what you want and your attempted code to create the array. And where is the `\u2019` character you are referring to? And how is it relevant to the need to create an array?

Comment: @rmaddy added some update.

Comment: The Unicode escapes are just there due to how the text is logged. Don't worry about them unless they appear to your user. Again, show your attempt to create an array from the data you get. Explain what troubles you are having and show what the array should look like.

Comment: @rmaddy added in at the end the entirety of code I am trying to use.  I want to take the result, and for each post made (in this case, 2) add an object to an NSMutableArray.  Then, for each of those objects, I use custom class RSSEntry to sort through everything, and add those objects to a different NSMutableArray

Comment: What's the problem then? What's the output of your log statements? How are results different from what you want?

Comment: Everything is null @rmaddy

Comment: Define "everything". Please don't make us play 20 questions with you. If you want help you need to provide details. Is `result` `nil`? Debug the code step by step. See where it doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: @rmaddy I have the NSLog for result in my question, where it has the data part.

Comment: @rmaddy self.arrayName has a NSDictionary with 1 object and that object has 2 arrays, that matches up with result.  However, when trying to get those into RSSEntry, it turns up null.

Comment: When I change from result to self.arrayName it has the format of 
`(
        (
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-08-08T20:32:01+0000";
            id = "116178611870507_533557976799233";
            message = "Message1";
            picture = "picture url";
        },
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-08-08T13:19:59+0000";
            id = "116178611870507_533557810132583";
            message = Message2;}
    )
)`

Since this array only has one object, I think it isn't properly creating a new array with multiple objects each containing its own message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is these two lines:

```
self.arrayName = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[self.arrayName addObject:[result objectForKey:@"data"]];
```

You create an array and then you add an array to that one (`[result objectForKey:@"data"]` returns an array).

Replace those two lines with:

```
self.arrayName = [result[@"data"] mutableCopy];
```

Now `self.arrayName` will contain an array with the two desired dictionaries.

You can also improve your code by using more modern syntax:

```
if (!error) {
    // NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);
    self.arrayName = [result[@"data"] mutableCopy];
    // NSLog(@"%@", self.arrayName);
    NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)self.arrayName.count);
    for (NSDictionary *myArrayElement in self.arrayName) {
        NSString *theMessage = myArrayElement[@"message"];
        // NSLog(@"%@", theMessage);
        RSSEntry *entry = [[[RSSEntry alloc] initWithBlogTitle:@"Test"
                              articleTitle:@"Testing"
                              articleUrl:@"TestingURL"
                              articleDate:[NSDate date]
                              articleImage:theMessage] autorelease];
        [self.theEntries addObject:entry];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", self.theEntries);
} else {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
}
```